# How to change border - bottom color through JS

Tags: javascript

```js
var subContent = document.getElementsByClassName("canChoose")[0];
subContent.style.borderBottomColor = "red";
```

```css
.calendar-content .canChoose:after {
 width: 20px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 border-bottom: 8px solid #5A8C19;
 border-radius: 10px;
 content: "";
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar-content"><div class="canChoose"></div></div>
```

I tried to change the color, but it didn't work:

```
subContent.style.borderBottomColor = "red";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

object.style.borderBottom = "width style color|initial|inherit"

Comment: It's after pseudo-class selector.

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct way to do it. maybe you have wrong selector?

also try doing *borderBottom = "1px solid red"*

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("#ElemenetName").style.borderBottom = "thick solid #00"

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to manipulate the pseudo-selector `:after` **directly through JavaScript**, because it doesn't technically exist in the DOM. There [**are workarounds**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21709814/2341603) depending on specific use case, though unfortunately these workarounds only allow you to manipulate the **content** (not the styling) of pseudo-selectors.

As such, you simply **cannot** change the colour of a border in `:after`, and your only option is to make use of the element directly.

If you weren't making use of `:after`, and were instead targeting the element directly, you'd be looking for `.style.borderBottom`:

```js
var target = document.getElementsByClassName('canChoose')[0];
target.style.borderBottom = "8px solid red";
```

```css
.canChoose {
  width: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #5A8C19;
  border-radius: 10px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="canChoose"></div>
```

Note that there's no JavaScript method to access the colour directly. Instead, you have to type out the full border declaration as you would for CSS (like `8px solid red`).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: It's not impossible, just [not straight forward](https://jsfiddle.net/c2n9Lh8t/)...

Comment: This is my JavaScript code,How should I change?                                               for(var i = 1; i <= monDaynum; i++) {
    var subContent = document.createElement("div");
    subContent.className = "canChoose";
    if(nowDay === i) {
     //subContent.style.borderBottomColor = "red";
    } else {}
    if(i == nowDay) {
     subContent.classList.add("today");
    }
    subContent.innerHTML = i;
    el.appendChild(subContent);
   }

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly change the style of pseudo elements with JavaScript, since they are not DOM elements.

However, you can achieve this by adding a class to the element you want to change.

```js
var subContent = document.getElementsByClassName("canChoose")[0];
subContent.className += " error";
```

```css
.calendar-content .canChoose:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #5A8C19;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.calendar-content .canChoose.error:after {
  border-bottom-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar-content"><div class="canChoose"></div></div>
```

Note, that contrary to some of the answers in this post, if you were to style the element directly (versus `:after` pseudo element), your code works perfectly, as demonstrated below.

```js
var subContent = document.getElementsByClassName("canChoose")[0];
subContent.style.borderBottomColor = "red";
```

```css
.calendar-content .canChoose {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #5A8C19;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar-content"><div class="canChoose"></div></div>
```

Comment: you could also only add `.calendar-content .canChoose.error:after { border-bottom-color: red;}`  no need to duplicate all the values that still apply.

Comment: This is my JavaScript code,How should I change?                                               for(var i = 1; i <= monDaynum; i++) {
    var subContent = document.createElement("div");
    subContent.className = "canChoose";
    if(nowDay === i) {
     //subContent.style.borderBottomColor = "red";
    } else {}
    if(i == nowDay) {
     subContent.classList.add("today");
    }
    subContent.innerHTML = i;
    el.appendChild(subContent);
   }

Comment: Add a CSS block to style any element that has both the `canChoose` class, plus an additional class, making its border color red.  (I just named it `error` because I thought this was to style content that has an error.)  In your JavaScript, all you need to change is this line:  `subContent.style.borderBottomColor = "red"` to `subContent.className += " your-additional-class-name";`

Comment: Or, as you suggest, `subContent.classList.add("your-additional-class-name")`;